# Change and Update parameter value when Onchange combobox triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have a problem to change url parameter when event onchange triggered in combobox.
Here is the preview :
[image]

My default url like this :

```
http://reserv_book.php?id=1 the number id is according to row (from database).
```

When i select in Cart combobox i want to add parameter cart=standard or cart=extra according to combobox value.
So URL update like this :

```
http://reserv_book.php?id=1&cart=standard
```

When i select in Caddy combobox i want to add parameter caddy=standard or caddy=extra according to combobox value.
So URL update like this :

```
http://reserv_book.php?id=1&cart=standard&caddy=standard
```

Here is my function that called when onChange event in combobox triggered.

```
function changeValue(type, id) {
        var valCart = document.getElementById("cart").value;
        var valCaddy = document.getElementById("caddy").value;

        if (type == "cart") {
            //alert("Cart : "+val+" , "+id);


            $("a.book").each(function() {
               var link = "reserv_book.php?id="+id+"&caddy="+ valCaddy +"&cart=";

               if (valCart == "standard") {
                    $(this).attr("href", link + 'standard');
               } else {
                    $(this).attr("href", link + 'extra');
               }
            });

        } else {
            //alert("Caddy : "+val+" , "+id);

            $("a.book").each(function() {
               var link = "reserv_book.php?id="+id+"&cart="+ valCart +"&caddy=";

               if (valCaddy == "standard") {
                    $(this).attr("href", link + 'standard');
               } else {
                    $(this).attr("href", link + 'extra');
               }
            });
        }
    }
```

And this is html file in combobox :

```
<table width="100%" class="ry-table-gold" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Player(s)</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Caddy</th>
          <th>Cart</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Oct 28 2013</td>
        <td>14:50</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>IDR 450,000.0</td>
        <td>
            <select id="caddy" onchange="changeValue('caddy',1)">
            <option value="standard">Standard</option>
            <option value="extra">Extra</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="cart" onchange="changeValue('cart',1)">
            <option value="standard">Standard</option>
            <option value="extra">Extra</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="reserv_book.php?id=1" class="ry-btnbook book">Book Now</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Oct 10 2013</td>
        <td>14:00</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>IDR 700,000.0</td>
        <td>
            <select id="caddy" onchange="changeValue('caddy',2)">
                <option value="standard">Standard</option>
                <option value="extra">Extra</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="cart" onchange="changeValue('cart',2)">
                <option value="standard">Standard</option>
                <option value="extra">Extra</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="reserv_book.php?id=2" class="ry-btnbook book">Book Now</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Another problem is, if the data cart and caddy in first row changed. It affect to another row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find closest tr and search for links inside the table row. Since you are using inline handlers you need to pass additional argument.

```
function changeValue(type, id, element) {
    var valCart = $("#cart").val(); //use val to get the value of select.
    var valCaddy = $("#caddy").val();

    if (type == "cart") {
        //alert("Cart : "+val+" , "+id);

        $(element).closest("tr").find("a.book").each(function() {
           var link = "reserv_book.php?id="+id+"&caddy="+ valCaddy +"&cart=";

           if (valCart == "standard") {
                $(this).attr("href", link + 'standard');
           } else {
                $(this).attr("href", link + 'extra');
           }
        });

    } else {
        ...
        //same here
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<select id="cart" onchange="changeValue('cart',1, this)">
     <option value="standard">Standard</option>
     <option value="extra">Extra</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But still return wrong value, when i change the combobox value.

Comment: @fanjavaid Wrong value? Could you plz create an example (www.jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue.